# Inherit from a Swift class in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, inheritance

I'm successfully mixing and matching Obj-C and Swift in an Xcode 7 project. However, I can't seem to figure out how, in an Objective C class, to inherit from a Swift class (and yes I know about declaring that Swift class as `@objc` for visibility). In this case the desired Swift superclass `MySwiftViewController` is a subclass of `UIViewController`. For now, in Obj-C, I'm inheriting directly from `UIViewController` and not gaining access to the capabilities I added in `MySwiftViewController`.

Here's what i understand:

-- To declare an Obj-C class as inheriting from something, that must be in the .h file after the ':':

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface RootViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
@end
```

-- To make Swift classes visible, that is `#import`ed:

```
#import "MyProject-Swift.h"
```

However, you cannot import the Swift auto-generated bridging header into the Obj-C **.h** file. You also cannot forward-declare an opaque superclass with `@class`. So, is this possible and how?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's not possible to subclass a Swift class in Objective-C. Straight from the docs:

> You cannot subclass a Swift class in Objective-C.

See Apple's [guide on interoperability](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH10-ID136) for more details on what you can and cannot access with Objective-C.

Comment: Here is the link to the documentation - https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/Migration.html

Answer (score 3):

As for Xcode 8.0 and earlier there is dirty-hacky solution, that probably will be fixed in the future.

If you want to subclass from swift file, you can add `objc_subclassing_restricted` attribute. You can make it as macro for convenience.
Code:

Swift class.

```
import Foundation

class SwiftClass : NSObject {
  func say() {
    print("hi");
  }
}
```

Objc class:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

#import "test-Swift.h"

#define SWIFT_SUBCLASS __attribute__((objc_subclassing_restricted))

SWIFT_SUBCLASS
@interface ObjcClass : SwiftClass
- (instancetype)init;
@end
@implementation ObjcClass
- (void)say {
  NSLog(@"oops");
}
@end
```

But, as I understand, it is not supported, and **you may have any sort of bugs because of it.** So it is not guide to action, and more like curious thing to know.

Comment: I can confirm that this workaround compiles successfully on Xcode 8.1 but the class is not there, so the build fails in linker phase.

Comment: Can you provide more specific example? I just build and run above code on Xcode 8.2.1. It works well, and even more `[[ObjcClass alloc] init] say]` prints out "oops" without any error.

Comment: Not working for me on Xcode 8.3.2. Get the "cannot subclass" error on the `@implementation` line (without the __attribute__, I already get it on the `@interface` line)

Answer (score -1):

In fact, it can be achieved by category:

**Swift code**

```
import UIKit

@objc open class TestModel: NSObject {
    @objc var testName: String = String()
}
```

**Objective C .h file code**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

#import "Test-Swift.h"


@interface TestModel (Add)
- (void)configTestName;
@end
```

**Objective C .m file code**

```
#import "TestModel+Add.h"

@implementation TestModel (Add)

- (void)configTestName {
    self.testName = @"12323";
}

@end
```