# Unable to make my base class of objective-c class as swift class

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, protocols

I have used InteractiveSideMenu which is swift library. Now I want to adopt swift protocol into my objective-c class for that I have to make my objective class's base class to swift class which is somehow disallow.I don't know how to achieve this. can somebody help me out on this?

```
@interface my_objectiveC_Class : UIViewController 
{

}
```

Now, instead of UIViewController class I have to make it some swift class like MenuViewController but its not allowed to make swift class as base class of objective-c class.

Basically I need to adopt swift protocol inside my objective-c class.

Comment: I think you should annotate it with `@objc`:

`@objc public my_objectiveC_Class : UIViewController`

Comment: Protocols and classes are different things, you *can* let an objc class inherit from a Swift base class if you add a bridging header, you *can not* use a swift protocol on an objc class.

Comment: @MoayadAlkouz I think objective-c class don't need "@objc" annotation. you mean my swift class ?  which I have done already. thanks.

Comment: @kevin "can let an objc class inherit from a Swift base class" ?  Ok. then i have done bridging already.
 
"Defines Module": YES.
"Always Embed Swift Standard Libraries" : YES.
"Install Objective-C Compatibility Header" : YES.

#import <MyProject-Swift.h> 

Still it says : Cannot find interface declaration for 'MenuViewController', superclass of 'my_objectiveC_Class'; did you mean 'UIViewController'?

Comment: @MoayadAlkouz it also says : Cannot subclass a class that was declared with the 'objc_subclassing_restricted' attribute

Comment: @kevin according to this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35244592/inherit-from-a-swift-class-in-objective-c , we can't inherit from swift class in objective-c class.

Answer (score 1):

To use any `Swift` code into `Objective-C` or `Objective-C` code into `Swift` you need a `Bridging-Header` to let your compiler translate between two languages.

See this [AppleDoc](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html)